# I am working on my nuxt project with supabase

Tags: nuxt.js, supabase, internal-server-error

I made website for car sellers, and i want to user send message to ask seller for car info, and i want to that message go to my supabase but i always get Internal Server Error , status 500,
can someone please help , here u a picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqJ2O.png)

I want to user can send message to sellers

Comment: The 412 error is unrelated?